# Submit data from a button POST request

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have a problem, I'm trying to POST data from a button. This is my code:

```
 <% parsedData["Search"].forEach(function(movie){ %>
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="<%= movie.Poster %>" alt="<%= movie.Title %> Poster">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title"><%= movie.Title %> </h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <form action="/results" method="POST"> 
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
<% }); %>
```

I would like to pass the value of movie.Title and movie.Poster to /results without having to do it through an input, so when the user clicks the button the movie metadata is sent to the POST request /results

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this without `<input>`s? Just use hidden ones.

Comment: Didn't know about hidden input, thank you so much! Have a good night